# Android Equivalent of XCode Instruments

Tags: android, xcode, instruments

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent to the Xcode Instruments (Memory, CPU tools) for Android? Is DDMS really my only option?

Comment: The one provided by Android/Google is DDMS, but as for everything else in Android, you can always look for open alternatives or for extreme cases make your own :) Remember everything is open source for Android. Google is working on Android Studio, which is suppose to be a tailored version of Ecllipse for Android developers. In other words the tools should be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks LuckyMe. Yes, I wanted a reality check really. I suspected this was the case but kept thinking there must be something besides DDMS. Obviously not. Looking forward to Android Studio.

Comment: You should know that DDMS can currently be accessed through Eclipse, (in case you were struggling with the command prompt method). And you are welcome, any time.

Comment: Did you ever find any tool that comes close to Instruments?

Comment: Just want to reask the question again in 2017 :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main memory/CPU profiling tools for Android apps:

- [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), a graphical thread execution profiler
- [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), a memory analyzer for Java

While they're not as tightly integrated as Instruments, these tools are powerful and fairly easy to learn. Both are accessible from DDMS via the button bar above the list of running processes, but they're separate tools and offer much more than the basic method/allocation profiling that's provided within DDMS itself.